# Calling Python class method which is in another file

Tags: python, python-3.x

From a main fill (or another class file), I would instantiate a class and call a method.

Knowing many languages and learning Python: this must be very easy, but could not find a good example. So, if you show me another post or answer, please feel free.

My config is:

- All files are in the same folder (`main.py` and `MathsOperations.py`)
- Python 3.7
- IDE: Pycharm 2020.2 (just upgraded)
- Starting (Running) the `main.py` in the folder.

The Class file:

```
class MathsOperations:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.a = x
        self.b = y
    def testAddition (self):
        return (self.a + self.b)

    def testMultiplication (self):
        return (self.a * self.b)
```

**Try-1:** The main file:

```
from . import MathsOperations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xyz = MathsOperations(2, 3)
    print( xyz.testAddition())
```

I get the error: `ImportError: cannot import name 'MathsOperations' from '__main__'`

**Try-2**: import in

```
import MathsOperations;

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xyz = MathsOperations(2, 3)
    print( xyz.testAddition())
```

Gives error: `No module named MathOperations`

**Try-3**: using dot notation with file

```
from .MathsOperations import MathsOperations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xyz = MathsOperations(2, 3)
    print( xyz.testAddition())
```

Gives error: `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.MathsOperations'; '__main__' is not a package`

**SOLUTION**: using from and import of python file

This works thanks to @Surya R and @Chad S.

```
from MathsOperations import MathsOperations

if __name__ == '__main__':
    xyz = MathsOperations(2, 3)
    print( xyz.testAddition())
```

This gives a WARNING in PyCharm but that one can be ignored!

Comment: What is the name of the file containing the definition of `MathsOperations`?  Where is it located relative to the main file?

Comment: Can you show a tree of your directory structure?

Comment: Please see updated question.

Comment: `from MathsOperations import MathsOperations`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to solve this you have to understand the dot in the line 1 which is important

The dot in the module name is used for relative module import
You can use more than one dot, referring not to the current package but its parent(s). This should only be used within packages, in the main module one should always use absolute module names.

let me know your folder's structure so that we could find the right import statement

incase to import a file

```
import file
```

you can use

```
from yourfilenmae import yourclassname
```

if you wanna use dot things refer this one [dot syntax to import files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0aHw0.png)

Comment: @tm1701 this is the correct answer, `from main import MathsOperations`

Comment: Gives this error: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '__main__.MathsOperations'; '__main__' is not a package

Comment: This works: from MathsOperations import MathsOperations. Yes, it gives an error message in PyCharm, still it works.